# Kendo UI TreeView Chekbox Submit button

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-treeview

Assuming I had a program that look like [this](https://dojo.telerik.com/oSIxAqAM).
In my dataSource I had an ID `(moduleID, groupID, programID)` and the name itself.
What I want, went checkbox is *true or checked* then I click on Submit button it will fetch the selected ID's.

How to achieve this?
[DEMO IN DOJO](https://dojo.telerik.com/oSIxAqAM)

Comment: Did you check Telerik's example on https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/checkboxes? They show you how to get a list of selected indexes.

Comment: thank you for that, I try had it appear result like this `LA1,,,,LA6,,,,LA12` because I had different ID name. Any idea how make only 1 coma? Plus how do I combine with another treeView id "Admin & System"? [DEMO](https://dojo.telerik.com/oSIxAqAM/2)

Comment: To get rid of the empty strings between the comas, replace:
    checkedNodes.join(",") with  checkedNodes.filter(x => !!x).join(",") - this filters out the falsy values, like zeros and empty strings. (If 0 is a correct id, adapt the filtering function accordingly.)

Comment: To combine nodes from both trees, gather the nodes from the second one the same was as you do from the first one, to say the array checkedNodes2, and concatenate the results:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Comment: @GaloisGirl do you mind to show me how to combine nodes from both trees? I had no idea where to concatenate the result. [Current Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/IYEvALiY)

Comment: I tried to fix a small typo, hope this is what you intended?
[updated demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/IYEvALiY/3)

Comment: @dontbannedmeagain you were almost there: [updated demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/IYEvALiY/7)